# how to automate multi user login for browser scenarios

Tags: session

Currently when i try to login with mutli users only one login is allowed in the browser. my requirement is to be able to login with multi logins. I'm using IE if it helps.

you response will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)?

Answer (score 1):

newer IE version have an InPrivate mode. this way you can open a second session and login as another user.

have a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/open-ies-private-browsing-mode-the-easy-way/) link to see how you can enable the InPrivate mode